# Problema ao usar o LIKE do Sql no AngularJS

Tags: sql, angularjs

Venho há alguns dias tendo problema em fazer uma busca no meu app usando `AngularJS` e hoje consegui descobrir o motivo: Na consulta `SQL` com `LIKE`, ele simplesmente não está recebendo o parâmetro como deveria.

Minha função está assim:

```
self.searchAll = function(text) {
  var parameters = [text];

  return DBA.query("SELECT id, place_name FROM tblPlaces WHERE place_name LIKE '%(?)%'", parameters)
    .then(function(result) {
      return DBA.getAll(result);
  });
}
```

Acho que pelo fato do `(?)` estar colado com os `%%`, ele não reconheça que ali deveria se encaixar o parâmetro text. Resolvi então fazer uns testes e colocar algum texto direto na query, sem vir por parâmetro e funcionou.

Tentei também concatenar o texto, pra ver se dessa forma funcionaria, porque caso funcionasse eu poderia tentar passar o parâmetro dessa forma. Mas também não funcionou, ele me retorna um erro do SQLite.

Então me surgiram duas dúvidas: Existe a possibilidade de fazer essa busca usando o LIKE e recebendo esse texto por parâmetro do jeito que está aí na função? Ou seria melhor que eu fizesse um SELECT geral, transformasse em um objeto JSON e fizesse o uso do filter do Angular?

**Obs:** Essa busca que estou tentando fazer é em uma tela que lista várias categorias e o usuário poderá pesquisar por produtos de forma geral.

Comment: seu banco é SQLite?  e sua aplicação AngularJS ?

Comment: Tente inverter as áspas simples com as duplas

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 Sim. É um app com Ionic.

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe Inverti as aspas, mas o problema persiste.

Answer (score 2):

Acabei de testar uma coisa que nem sequer tinha passado pela minha cabeça: Concatenar os `%%` com o parâmetro já na variável `parameters`. E funcionou!

```
self.searchAll = function(nameSearch) {
  var parameters = ["%"+nameSearch+"%"];

  return DBA.query('SELECT id, place_name FROM tblPlaces WHERE place_name LIKE ?', parameters)
    .then(function(result) {
      return DBA.getAll(result);
});
}
```

Comment: Boa, mas essa forma não seria bem a ideal, você teria que ter uma solução que fuja do [SQL Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL) .

Comment: `txtUserId = getRequestString("UserId");
sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = @0";
command = new SqlCommand(sql);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0",txtUserID);
command.ExecuteReader();` algo assim.

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 Entendi. Vou refazer aqui então, muito obrigado!

Comment: Esse exemplo é em C# não sei como é usando AngularJS.

Comment: Certo, mas mesmo assim vou pesquisar aqui como refazer essa query para fugir do SQL Injection.